# Use local image source in html <img> element

Tags: javascript, html

I have image on my machine that I want to display in img element.

```
<img class="card-image" src="'file:///C:/Users/.../KITCHEN/imgname.png'"/>
```

But I get this error:

```
1 Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Users/.../KITCHEN/imgname.png
```

Any idea how to fix this issue.

**UPDATE:**
images outside the project folder

Comment: have the image in the same folder as the html and don't call it with `file:` etc.

Comment: Why an absolute path? Are your images outside the project folder?

Comment: @s.kuznetsov yes, it outside of the app folder

Comment: Could convert it to base64 instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should not give an exact local path. You can use a relative path. Here is detailed explanation.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_src.asp